# Cache DB table data on application start

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, caching

I've a database table with some meta-data, which doesn't change between releases. I want to be able to cache this meta-data on application start so that I can use it just like an ENUM. May be cache in a bean. Is there a way to do that in Java ? I'm using spring framework in my webapp. I found memcached through search but I think that is too heavy in terms of learning curve and use for what I want to store. My table is a small one with an ID and value corresponding to it and there will be 10s of records only.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement as such wont even require any cache learning, you can use Spring life cycle methods for this. Like below

```
public class DBCache implements InitializingBean { 
private Map dataCache;
public void afterPropertiesSet() { 
// perform db hit and populate dataCache; } 
} 
public Map getCacheData(){//RETURN THE DATA OR WHATEVER FORMAT YOU NEED//}
```

The method afterPropertiesSet is called by Spring framework. Although sometimes its suggested not to implement InitializingBean as it couples with Spring, then  use may also choose @PostConstruct annotation on a method you wanted to get callback when application starts.